# Could citing a database like libgen get one into trouble?

Tags: thesis

Databases like libgen are considered illegal in most countries, I understand. So, if someone acknowledges libgen as the database from which a book has been retrieved on the Reference List, could he/she get into trouble?

This is in cases, where you have to cite the database, apart from the book. Suppose, you cite an e-book or an online article, you have to include the database too in certain referencing systems.

Comment: Why would you want to cite libgen as opposed to just citing the book?

Comment: I am afraid this question is based on an incorrect understanding as a premise: there are, as far as I know, no cases in which you have to cite the source where you obtained a certain book. Have you ever read "source: university of Stanford library" in a citation section, for instance? I am voting to close this question as unclear until you provide an explicit example or otherwise improve it.

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [Citing paywalled articles accessed via illegal web sharing](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/125570/7734), [Should I let my professor know that I cited a text written by him…that I pirated from online](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/52509/7734).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni [APA style](https://apastyle.apa.org/learn/quick-guide-on-references#E-Books) requires the URL for e books. If you only used the e book you need to cite the e book, even if there is a paper version available.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft in both the linked questions you are getting an online version of the printed version of the material. Ebooks are often not identical to the printed version (at a minimum the generally the page numbering is different). Therefore some citation styles require the URL, which makes this question very different.

Comment: @StrongBad What do you mean with "the URL for an e-book"? An e-book often is a pdf / epub / etc. file; it doesn't come with a URL. Many books have an associated official web page on the editor's website; maybe you mean that, but then you can cite it no matter where you got the book. Could you give an explicit example of an e-book that you would have trouble citing?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni APA is clear, they want the retrieved from URL. You cannot cite an alternative URL if you didn't go there since you cannot be sure it is the same version.

Comment: @StrongBad Suppose I send you a pdf copy of an e-book via e-mail. What should you write in the citation according to APA?

Comment: If you really need to, you can use the ISBN to search for another source that you can use instead. This is similar to Wikipedia. Professors don't allow Wikipedia as a source but they won't complain if you find something on Wikipedia and then research the source found on Wikipedia. I assume it was easier for you to find the information on libgen but now that you have the information, it shouldn't be hard to find that information using the ISBN or exact title from a legit source.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Please do not vote for "unclear" because you don't like the question.  The question is completely clear, and was before it was edited.  I'm not claiming it is a good question, though.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I'm following the guideline suggested in my answer [here on meta](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3549/why-are-we-challenging-the-premise-rather-than-answering-the-question-question/3553#3553). It is at +32 votes (+34/-2) currently, so I would say there is some consensus that it's a reasonable policy.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni That was a very different situation, and you will notice a contradictory answer with more votes above it.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I don't think the other answer is contradictory, and I think that the situation is very similar.

Answer (score 11):

The databases are illegal in that they violate copyright law. The owner of the database is clearly in violation of the law, but users of the database are generally not. That said, I can imagine some authors would be upset to see a published link to a pirated version of their book. Why not just go to the library and confirm that the printed version matches the online version.

Comment: Will there ever be a [Capitol Records, Inc. v. Thomas-Rasset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitol_Records,_Inc._v._Thomas-Rasset) of academic e-books...?

Comment: @smci Not if we stand up and fight it.  And if we *really* believe that everyone should have access to a good library, then that's what we'll do.

Comment: @Diagon: [United States v. Aaron Swartz case (JSTOR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_Swartz#United_States_v._Aaron_Swartz_case), I suppose. Except sadly he committed suicide, so we won't know the outcome.

Comment: @smci - I think the fight's going to be in the streets; and that's a matter of solidarity.  Courts will be forced to follow along later.